# what does "..." mean and difference between ... and pass in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Well...When I define a function that does not perform certain actions I don't understand what the difference between `...` and `pass`. For example, the following two pieces of code:

```
def _clear() -> None: ...
def _clear() -> None: pass
```

They are the same, right? Either one can be used? I sincerely hope someone can help me thoroughly understand it. Thanks...

Comment: Note that I only attempted to answer the second half of this question which is not the same as that duplicate. The first half is the same.

Answer (score 1):

`pass` is the standard way to say that a function does not do anything.

Placing the ellipsis object does yield valid code just like `def _clear() -> None: x = 5`, but most IDEs and static analysis tools will complain that the statement has no effect.